# General parameter table in SCIP in .zpl-format

Tags: linear-programming, scip

I am tring to solve the following linear program with SCIP and the .zpl-format:

[image]

where as c, p and A are defined the following way:

[image]

I already came up with a way to solve it:

```
param n := 1000;
set N := {1 .. n};
param c[<i> in N] := i/n ;



var p[<i> in N] real >= 0; 
set A := N * N;

set O := {<i,j> in A with i < j};
set D := {<i,j> in A with i == j};
set U := {<i,j> in A with i > j};

param a[<i,j> in O] := 0;
param b[<i,j> in D] := i;
param g[<i,j> in U] := 1;

maximize prob: sum <i> in N : c[i] * p[i];

subto cond2:
     forall <i> in N do
        sum <j> in N with i>= j do 
            if(i ==j) then b[i,j] * p[j] 
                      else g[i,j] * p[j] end <= 1 ;
```

For the matrix A I subdivided the 3 cases (Upper triangle being 0, diagonal being i, and lower traingle being 1) in three parameters, namely param a,b and g.

I was wondering whether there is a more elegant solution by having all three cases in only one parameter, so for the condition at the end I can basically just sum over one parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can define a function like:

```
defnumb v(i,j) := if i < j then 0 else if i == j then i else 1 end end;
```

Afterwards, you can rewrite constraint:

```
subto cond2:
 forall <i> in N do
    sum <j> in N with i>= j do v(i,j) * p[j] <= 1;
```

I hope this is elegant enough.

Best,
Jakob